# Facebook Ads & Google Tag Manager

Tags: facebook, google-tag-manager

We are using Google Tag Manager and Google Optimize to do A/B testing and tracking on one of our gridsome based websites.

We have discovered that Facebook has been rejecting our ads because our load times are to long.

We have debug the problem as being the anti-flickr layer for Google Tag Manager taking too long to load. However if we shorten the timeout within the pixel code then the Google Optimize layer times out.

Is there anyone that can provide some more insight into using Google Tag Manager with Facebook Advertising, and optmizing the pixels so they work in harmony?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take the time to review the [help on asking questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking), in particular [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and this [Question Checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) to see what sort of question you can ask here and what you need to include so you get the help you need